# redux reducer not called

Tags: redux, react-redux

Can someone help me figure out why this simple redux implementation is not calling the reducer on the anchor tag click?

The action gets initiated on each click, while the reducer only once when the program starts.

Any pointer appreaciated.

```
// action
const changeText = (text) => {
    console.log('action changeDate')
    return {
      type: 'CHANGE_TEXT',
      text
    };
};

// reducer
const changeTextReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  console.log('reducer changeTextReducer')
  return [
      ...state,
    {
      text: 'Some Text'
    }
  ]

}


class Sales extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)

  }

  handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.onClick('test')

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="content">
          <a href="" onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)} > click me </a>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log('mapStateToProps', state)
  return {changeTextReducer: state.text}
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onClick: (dates) => {
      dispatch(changeText(dates))
    }
  }
};

const SalesApp = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Sales);

export default SalesApp



// store
const store = createStore(
    allReducers, composeWithDevTools(
        applyMiddleware(
            thunkMiddleware, // lets us dispatch() functions
            createLogger // neat middleware that logs actions
        ),

    )
);
```

Comment: How do create your redux store?

Comment: Added the store to the bottom of the code block

Comment: Variable `allReducers` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: It is, sorry for not copying it here. I found an issue. Not sure why but by commenting out the ```createLogger``` middleware all works

Comment: Cool, so you narrowed it down and can examine the problem now.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the help.